# Does an automotive DC generator care about battery voltage?

Tags: generator

Can a 6 volt positive ground generator be used in a 12 volt negative ground system? The question pertains to converting a 6 volt positive ground automobile to a 12 volt negative ground system. The majority of online automotive forums state that the field coils must be changed when converting to 12 volts. My understanding of a DC generator is that it will continue to increase voltage output until regulated, either by a voltage regulator or by the battery. So I would think only the voltage regulator would have to be changed when converting to a 12 volt system. The field coils will reverse polarity when polarized on the first connection of the 12 volt battery correct?

Comment: Can you make an apple into an orange? Not to sound trite but the generator, chassis is its ground, so only the 'hot' wire needs to run to the battery. You would have to tear apart the generator to reverse the connections from the rectifiers, usually 3-phase, and ground the negative output. Good luck with that...

Comment: I suspect that using the original field coils will mean that a higher idle speed will be required to keep the battery from discharging at idle. If the field current is increased too much, the field will burn out.

Comment: the big question is `why are you thinking of doing this?` ....... what problem are you trying to solve? ...... this appears to be an XY problem

Comment: @Sparky256: In US English usage, a "generator" has brushes, an "alternator" has rectifiers.  They didn't have silicon diodes in 1936...

Comment: So you asked the people with real experience, but you didn't like the answer so you come here?

Comment: Assuming the iron doesn't saturate, if the generator is wound for 6V and you try to run it on 12, you'll need to double the field current.  You can do that, because you have twice the voltage to force current through the field coils -- but those poor coils will be dissipating four times the heat due to \$I^2 R\$ losses.  You want to have the thing rewound so that half the field current generates the same field, and that same field generates twice the voltage.  Find a shop that rewinds generators, or if your car is common enough, just buy a 12V from someone who does that sort of thing.

Comment: Note that reversing the polarity is a snap, because it's got separate field excitation.  Change the polarity if the field, and the 'lectricity coming out of the thing changes polarity.

Comment: yeah, I converted my morris minor to negative earth by reversing the battery. even the tube radio continued to work. changing the voltage will be the tricky bit. but yeah re-winding the generator with twice as many turns on the field and the rotor would fix that it'd need a new regulator too.  probably easier to fit an alternator.

Comment: @TimWescott I had the privilege of repairing the wiring on a car after an Electrical Engineer worked on it - did not understand that the body/chassis was the neutral wire, so all devices needed two wires to them, caused a massive amount of damage - I got paid though... He had **lots ** of experience on other electrical things though...

Comment: Iron saturation may well be an issue on doubling a generator's operating voltage, it'll  generally be able to achieve the voltage at open circuit, but under load it'll likely run out of oomph. A generator wound for 12V initially will likely have different windings on the armature (rotor) that generate a higher voltage (but less current) at the same field. Usually that's achieved by a lap/wave winding pattern change in the winding, and a rewind shop could to this but that that point either find a 12V generator, or just swap in an alternator if you're not concerned about original appearance.